# Google API - Oauth 2.0 Auth token flow

Tags: javascript, google-api, access-token

Context --

- I am building a web application that uses the Google Cal and Google+ API.
- I will need to obtain a refresh token, since once a user authenticates with the site/app, some of the calls happen behind the scenes after they have logged in (and many of them happen after 1 hour, of which the initial access_token is valid for)

As I understand it, here is the flow I must follow:

1. Register a Web Application API through Google console - done.
2. Prompt the user to authenticate with my application, done through a call using the following config vars:

---

```
  var config = {
    'client_id': MY_CLIENT_ID',
    'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'response_type': 'code',
    'access_type': 'offline'
  };
```

3. Then, using the Google object returned through the auth() call above, make another call to get the access_token and refresh_token.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=CODE_RETURNED
client_id=CLIENT_ID_RETURNED
client_secret=API_CLIENT_SECRET
redirect_uri=API_REDIRECT_API
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Yet, when I try to run this call I always get some type of error. Right now I am stuck getting the following:

```
{
  error: "redirect_uri_mismatch"
}
```

I have the following listed as my redirect uri both on the Google API settings page, and in code:

```
http://localhost/
```

Any advice from someone that has worked with this flow before?
Do I need to set up something differently for obtaining a refresh token?

Comment: Have you set the `redirect_uri` to the same value as in your Google Developers settings? Also I think you also need a `redirect_uri` for the first call.

Comment: redirect URI needs to map to a page for example: http://localhost/google-api-php-client-samples/oauth2.php

Comment: @DaImTo does that page have to exist? And if so, what does that page do?

Comment: Google says: The redirect URI that you set in the Developers Console determines where Google sends responses to your authentication requests. So I would assume for local testing this would be http://localhost/project/page.php (that I am making the call from and want to do logic based on the response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue as to why this whole process was failing was because I was not including the 'redirect_uri' in my initial call to get a code.

I should have had:

```
var config = {
    'client_id': MY_CLIENT_ID',
    'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'response_type': 'code',
    'access_type': 'offline',
    'redirect_uri': MY_REDIRECT_URI
 };
```

Then, that redirect_uri was hit with data, and I set up a simple node route to listen, generate, and then store the access and refresh tokens for each user that authenticated.